# "Backstage" VS "Backroom"

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning, difference

What do you call the area in which the cameraman, the director, the lighting and voice recording staff etc. work in a studio? (The other part would be the place where actors or reporter stand and act.)

I know two words for that, but I don't know if they work in this sense or at least which works better here?

[**Backstage:**](https://www.google.com/amp/s/dictionary.cambridge.org/amp/english/backstage)

> In the area behind the stage in a theatre, especially the rooms in which actors change their clothes or where equipment is kept.

[**Backroom:**](https://www.google.com/amp/s/dictionary.cambridge.org/amp/english/backroom)

> A room in which work or other activities are done out of public view or secretly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neither quite works.  "Backroom" is nothing to do with TV. It refers to actions done in secret, often illegally

> The banks are alleged to have made a backroom deal to manipulate exchange rates.

"Backstage" is possible, but tends to mean where the presenters or actors prepare.

> Jack waited backstage, practising his lines in his head.

In a TV studio, the main separation is between the *studio floor* and the *production control room*.  On the studio floor are the cameras, sound equipment as well as the presenters. The director sits in the control room.

A possible useful expression is "Behind the camera" or "behind the lens":

> Jody Foster started as a child actor, but most of her recent work has been behind the camera, as a director of several feature films.

Comment: That should be *Jodie* Foster.

Comment: "Backstage" and "behind the camera" are both good choices.  At Disney parks, resorts, and ships, the entirety of the property where guests don't go is known as "backstage".   The word ''-stage'' emphasizes the performance aspect of the jobs that are being done.  This is a very specific usage of the word; "behind the camera" is very good for movie production in general.